# How to insert x86 opcode data from .data segment bits in to operand instruction in x86 machine code?

Tags: x86, bootloader, opcode

I am working on an x86 bootloader written entirely in opcodes, no headers, all binary.

The problem is that Intel's ISA manual does NOT include how to include data segment bytes from .data segment code in to secondary operands of machine instructions in opcode format.

I have this so far:

```
1000 101w 110
```

That above code should be equivalent to the following:

```
MOV SI
```

However, I need to insert the data to the Source Index register containing the "Hello World" to be displayed on the screen in monochrome text video mode, like this:

```
MOV SI, HELLO_WORLD_BYTE_STRING
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader is loaded at fixed address (`0000:7C00`) from the BIOS, so if you put your string in some point in the code, you can reference it with an offset from the start of the program.

You can see this link http://www.vnutz.com/articles/PC_Bootsector_Programming_Tutorial_In_ASM

Comment: I don't think you really understand what I'm trying to do here. I need to know HOW to insert the operand of the memory address from the data byte segment as an operand to the Source Index register to use(in x86 opcodes).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here either. You say you want to "insert an operand into an operand". Do you mean that you want to write the values of the bytes in the data segment into the middle of an instruction? Or are you asking how to use the address of the bytes in the data segment as an instruction operand? My guess is the latter (as the former is just silly), in which case what you are really asking is "how do I get the runtime address of offset 1000 in the data segment?"

Answer (score 0):

Abstractions like separate code and data segments are provided by the assembler/linker toolchain. When you are writing raw machine code, you have to do that work yourself. You can choose to interleave code and data however you like so long as you ensure you don't accidentally try to execute code.

For the `mov` instruction you're trying to write, the simplest implementation is for the second operand to be an immediate word containing the address of the start of your string. That address will be wherever you decide to put the string data. (An assembler would pre-compute this value.) Thus, you want the opcode `0b1011 1110` followed by the low and high bytes of the address. Then `SI` will contain the pointer to the beginning of your string.

It will probably be more instructive for you to write this using an assembler, and then dissasemble that (either by hand or mechanically) to get a better idea of what the assembler is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   VALUE DB 0xFF
                mov bx, Offset VALUE
                mov di, Offset P1
                mov cs:[di+1], bx ; writing the offsetaddress of "VALUE" into
   P1: BE 00 10 mov si, 0x1000    ; <- this instruction inside of our codesegment
```

Dirk